# decode elements of arrays php array from json

Tags: php, wordpress, json

trying to get data from json, So far, I can see I have converted the data into a php array which displays it on the page, with the following code:

```
$jsonurl        =   'url';
$json           =   file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output    =   var_dump(json_decode($json,true));
```

This outputs the whole array, the json file stores the name of the business, address, image url, city, etc etc. What I'm confused about is how I just say echo out a list of just say the Name of the business plus the city, as simply printed text, rather then dumping the whole array onto the page.

Comment: please add the data you've got and the data you want. remember formatting

Comment: echo json_output[key name goes here][subkey name goes here]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can echo the data in a foreach loop:

```
$json_as_array = json_decode($json,true);
foreach ($json_as_array AS $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ': ' . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo it like a normal array value.

```
echo $array['key']['subkey']; // echoes value from array/key/subkey
```